# Category Theoretic Proof that $Lie(GL(n, \mathbb{C}))$ is isomorphic in the category of Lie Algebras to $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: category-theory, lie-algebras

Trying to follow the reasoning in Lee's Smooth Manifolds book that $Lie(GL(n, \mathbb{C}))$  is isomorphic in the category of Lie Algebras to $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})$.

He ends up with the following commutative diagram

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
Lie(GL(n, \mathbb{C})) @>{\cong}>> \mathfrak{gl}(n, \mathbb{C})\\
@V{\beta_*}VV @V{\alpha}VV\\
\beta_*(Lie(GL(2n, \mathbb{R}))) @>{\cong}>> \alpha(\mathfrak{gl}(n, \mathbb{C}))
\end{CD}

Where the maps $\beta_*$ and $\alpha$ are the standard injective lie algebra homorphism from $M(n, \mathbb{C}) \rightarrow  M(2n, \mathbb{R})$.

We have proven earlier that the bottom map is a Lie Algebra isomorphism and that the vertical maps are also Lie Algebra isomporphisms.

He then concludes that since the the top map is a vector space isomorphism, it is also a Lie Algebra isomorphism.

I must be missing something obvious, because I am not seeing how this follows. For one, we haven't even shown that it is a Lie Algebra homomorphism.

Comment: The map $\alpha$ is clearly an isomorphism, and hence we see that all of the spaces have the same dimension, so all the maps are bijective. Thus, the sought for isomorphism is just a matter of composing with the inverse of $\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks Tobias. The answer seems obvious in retrospect. I am pretty new to category theoretic reasoning, so your answer was helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ve written the top map as a composite of three Lie algebra isomorphisms, so it’s a Lie algebra isomorphism. Notice that this is not exactly an isomorphism between $GL(n\mathbb C)$ and $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb C)$, since the former is not in the category of Lie algebras. The application of the functor $Lie$ is doing something!

Comment: Corrected the error you mentioned. More explicitly, reworded to mention an isomorphism between $Lie(GL(n,C))$ and $\mathfrak{gl}(n, C)$.